# Dissolve in ogr / python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, ogr, performance

I have a set of ~100,000 polygons (.shp format). Using python and ogr I would like to dissolve them to one feature class to speed up other downstream operations. The command I am using is:

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" dissolved.shp input.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_Collect(Geometry),common_attribute from input GROUP BY common_attribute"`

The command takes some time to run (now over an hour, likely significantly longer). Doing the dissolve in ArcGIS and grouping by the common field results in the desired output in just a few seconds. My questions are (1) Why is ArcGIS so much faster? (2) How can I speed up this operation

Answer (score 3):

When you tell GDAL to use SQLite SQL dialect the most part of the work is done by Spatialite library. Couple of weeks ago another user reported that ST_Collect in Spatialite was pretty slow for any bigger tasks https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/t3QrvA1qQyg.

Week after that Alessandro Furieri announced about a code optimization which made ST_Collect about 400 times faster https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/drNS_tiquJc.

Unfortunately it will take some time before all GDAL users can enjoy this speedup. The fix must first go to released Spatialite version and GDAL must be build with that version. Those who can build programs can build Spatialite from the trunk and use that for building GDAL.

Comment: This is fascinating. I will mark this as answered but I want to ask first, do you have any ideas around how I could speed up the operation? Looks like using geopandas might be a good idea?

Comment: I am not sure but perhaps you can do what you want also with ST_Union. Try and tell us.

Comment: ST_Union is generally "orders of magnitude slower". See http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html The operation above ended up taking 3.5 hours. I am testing again with ST_Union now. Will test also using geopandas and update the question with results!

Comment: If you are open for using other tools I am rather sure that you can do your job in couple of minutes with OpenJUMP. Run it with 64-bit Java because OpenJUMP must do all the job in the memory. Tools-Analysis-Union/Dissolve/Merge is probably your tool with the Use an Attribute to Dissolve checked.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with OpenJUMP or programming in Java :-(  Additionally this analysis will be embedded in a larger system, which is all written in Python. This is why I'm looking for a pythonic solution

Comment: Well, it will take 10 minutes to get experienced and it does not hurt even if you will never use OpenJUMP. You can do that while you wait for the ST_Union to finalize. Download this http://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_snapshots/OpenJUMP-Portable-20151123-r4556-PLUS.zip/download, unzip, run the startup script from the bin-directory. OpenJUMP is based on JTS and GEOS is a C++ port of JTS so you have already been looking at the same code but from a different window.